# Finding the value of an unknown (2,k)

Tags: geometry, slope

If the straight line which passes throught the two points (3,1),(2,k) is parallel to the straight line which makes with the two coordinate axes in the second quadrant an isosceles triangle,find the value of k.

I am very confused am not sure how to solve this I would appreciate some help :)
Tag help please ?

Answer (score 0):

at first we compute the line through $$P_1(3;1)$$ and $$P_2(2;k)$$
this is $$y=(1-k)x+n$$ the second line is given by $$y=-x+n_1$$ and since both lines are parallel we get
$-1=1-k$ thus $$k=2$$

Comment: Dr. Graubner. Isn't the slope of the line in the second quadrant with equal y and x intercept =+1? You have -1.

Comment: with $y=mx+n$ we get $y=n$ for the $y$intercept and $x=\frac{-n}{m}$ for the $x$ intercept thus $\frac{-n}{m}=n$ and $m=-1$